# When downloading an image uploaded with Carrierwave to S3, I get a blank empty image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, fog

In my app, I use carrierwave and fog to upload images to S3. In the site, people can select a size and download the photo. When they click download, the program will use image magick to resize the image according to the selected size and then send it to the user. It works find and it send the file. But the problem is when I open the image it's blank! Nothing in the file. When I test it in my local server it works but in production it won't. Here's the action which sends the download :

```
def download
    @photo = Photo.friendly.find(params[:photo_id])
    if @photo.free?
        if params[:size].present?
            size = Size.find(params[:size])

            @photo.file.cache_stored_file!
            img = Magick::Image.read(@photo.file.file.file).first
            img.resize!(size.width, size.height)

            filename = "#{size.width}x#{size.height}-#{@photo.file.file.filename}"

            path = "#{Rails.root}/tempfreedownload/#{filename}"
            File.write(path, '')
            img.write path

            File.open(path, 'r') do |f|
                send_data f.read, type: 'image/png', filename: filename
            end

            File.delete(path)
            img.destroy!

            downloads = @photo.downloads + 1
            @photo.update_attribute(:downloads, downloads)
        else

        end

    else
        render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", layout: false, status: 404
    end
end
```

What might be the issue?

Comment: The usual best practice is to have a set of pre-defined sizes and let Carrierwave resize upon upload of that file, not as a just-in-time resizer. Would this be possible for your app?

Comment: No it won't work for my app. :-( it calculates a set of sizes for each photo .. basically get the width and devide by 5. So the sizes are dynamic